# WCF Globalization

Tags: wcf, globalization

I have a WCF service using netTcpBinding (the protocol should not be relevant but included it anyway).

I am having Culture issues with parsing dates.

Previously, using HTTP and System.Web, we can use the globalization element.

Unfortunately this has no effect in WCF.

I Have had trouble finding information/blogs about this.

Is there a way to set the culture in a WCF service in the configuration file?

Thanks very much

Russell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing intrinsic to WCF to help with this. However, there is a proposed web service standard called WSI18N which [Pablo Cibraro](http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/default.aspx), a pretty big name in the WCF community and a Microsoft MVP, has written [a CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WSI18N.aspx) about along with sample code to leverage this standard within WCF.

Comment: Thanks Drew. That certainly isn't a nice way of setting cultures (injecting into the WCF header information).  What about the scenario with an ESB that spans over multiple cultures? They can't communicate!